# ES6 project does not compile because modules not found

Tags: gulp, browserify, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to compile my ES6 classes into something that will work in the browser. Unfortunately, when I run gulp I get the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'IDB' from 'my-project/src'
```

So, just to get an idea of the project structure

```
my-project/
    gulpfile.js
    src/
        app.js
        IDB.js
```

Thats it. The files in `src` look like:

app.js

```
import IDB from 'IDB';

class View {
    constructor(options) { ... }
    render() { ... }
}
```

IDB.js

```
export class IDB { 
    constructor(options) { ... }
    render() { ... }
}
```

Finally, my `gulpfile.js` looks like:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    browserify('./src/app.js', { debug: true })
        .transform(to5ify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true})) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./')) // writes .map file
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

So, for some reason it doesn't resolve dependencies. Any suggestions what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your IDB.js file change it to

```
export default class IDB { 
    constructor(options) { ... }
    render() { ... }
}
```

That should correctly export the IDB class as the module.
And in the app.js change the import to be a relative path to the file like this:

```
import IDB from './IDB';
```